# The program does not show the calculations result... only zeroes

Tags: javascript, methods, getter-setter

```html
private static String name;   // attributes 
private static int numberQuize;
private static int totalScores;

public static String getName(){
    return name;
}
 
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public int getNumberQuize()
{
    return numberQuize;
}

public  void setNumberQuize(int numberQuize)
{
    this.numberQuize = numberQuize;
}

public static int getTotalScores()
{
    return totalScores;
}

public void setTotalScores(int totalScores)
{
    this.totalScores = totalScores;
}
 
public int totalScores(){      //Methods (adding quiz, totalScore, AverageScore)
    return totalScores;
}
 
public void addQuiz (int score){
    for (int quiz = 0; quiz >=0 ; quiz++){
        totalScores = totalScores + score;
    }
  
}
 
public double AverageScore (){    
    return (double) totalScores/numberQuize;
}
```

I wrote this code and it should display student name and total score nd the average score. However, the code runs but no answers it only show me zeroes.. I tried everything I know but still nothing is working..

Comment: It appears that your `void addQuiz()` method is an infinite loop, i.e. because you are testing whether `quiz` is greater than 0 and adding to `quiz`, `quiz` will always be greater than 0. That's one error I see right off the bat that might cause the issue you are getting. You also  need to show us how you are calling the above functions, i.e. your driver for us to really see what is going on. This program won't run as is.

Comment: Are you confusing Java and JavaScript? It's tagged as JavaScript, but the code looks like Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has an infinite loop here:

```
public void addQuiz (int score){
    for (int quiz = 0; quiz >=0 ; quiz++){
        totalScores = totalScores + score;
    }
}
```

`quiz` will always be `>= 0`.

I think your `addQuiz()` method should be:

```
public void addQuiz(int score){
    totalScores += score;
    numberQuize += 1;
}
```